# Get Specific website data into excel cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba and trying to write a code to extract some specific data from the below website into excel
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1646124/000114036115025436/xslFormDX01/primary_doc.xml

For example, I would like to pull some specific data like, Company name, Type(s) of Securities Offered, Offering and Sales Amounts, Clarification of Response (if Necessary), Type of Filing, Date of First Sale, etc.. from the above url to different excel cells but in the same row.

I have the the below code, but I don't understand how to use it for my purpose..

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    IE.navigate "kieskeurig.nl/zoeken/index.html?q=4960999543345"
    IE.Visible = False
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    'variable for document or data which need to be extracted out of webpage
    Set doc = IE.Document

    Dim dd As Variant
    dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("lgn")(0).outerHtml
    'Range("a1").Value = dd
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried - http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: thanks for your response.. I have the the below code, but I don't understand how to use it for my purpose..Sub GetData()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.navigate "http://www.kieskeurig.nl/zoeken/index.html?q=4960999543345"
IE.Visible = False
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE


Dim doc As HTMLDocument 'variable for document or data which need to be extracted out of webpage
Set doc = IE.document
Dim dd As Variant
dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("lgn")(0).outerHtml
'Range("a1").Value = dd

Comment: It looks like you haven't actually tried anything, yet - just found some code you don't understand. To scrape content from a webpage using VBA and write it to Excel you'll need some understanding of (1)  the VBA language (2) objects, methods and properties in VBA (3) the Document Object Model (DOM) (4) some specific objects such as the IE object (shown in your code) for reading a webpage successfully and navigating its content (5) some specific objects in Excel for outputting the scraped content to a workbook.

Comment: Can you please write a sample code for the above query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GetData()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.navigate "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1646124/000114036115025436/xslFormDX01/primary_doc.xml"
IE.Visible = False

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:016")) 
Dim doc As HTMLDocument 
Set doc = IE.document
Dim dd As Variant
dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("lgn")(0).outerHtml
'Range("a1").Value = dd
MsgBox dd

End Sub
```